# If $f \in BV_{1/2}([0, 1])$ then $f \in BV([0, 1])$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in BV_{1/2}([0, 1])$ to mean $\sum_{j=1}^{n} |f(x_{j})-f(x_{j-1})|^{1/2}<\infty$ whenever $\{x_{j}\}_{j=0}^{n}$ is a partition of $[0, 1]$.

How do I show that $f \in BV_{1/2}([0, 1])$ implies that $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0, 1]$?

Also, are the step functions and $|f|$ in $BV_{1/2}([0, 1])$ (provided $f$ is in $BV_{1/2}([0, 1])$?

---

For any step function $s(x)$ I know it takes just a finite set of finite values over $[0, 1]$ so the $\sum_{j=1}^{n} |s(x_{j}) - s(x_{j-1})|^{1/2}$ is going to be finite over any partition $\{x_{j}\}_{j=0}^{n}$.

Also, I think $|f|$ is going to be in $BV_{1/2}$ using the reverse triangle inequality.

I'm stuck on the problem of proving $f$ is of bounded variation and can't think of how to even start the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that from the fact that $ f \in \mathsf{BV}_{\frac{1}{2}}([0,1]) $ we have that $ f \in L^{\infty}([0,1])$ Hence, if you have a partition $ \mathbb{P}=\left\{x_0,\ldots,x_n \right\} $ you can estimate $$ |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|=|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|^{\frac{1}{2}} |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \sqrt{2 \left\| f \right\|_{\infty}}|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|^{\frac{1}{2}}  $$

Therefore $$ \sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})| \leq \sqrt{2 \left\| f \right\|_{\infty}}\sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \sqrt{2 \left\| f \right\|_{\infty}} \left\| f \right\|_{\mathsf{BV}_{\frac{1}{2}}([0,1])}  $$ which immediately yields the desired conclusion.